# Ошибка при записи двумерного массива

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть БД вида:

```
Время|X|Y|Z|Количество
18:04:23|24|0.63790|45|892
18:12:27|32|0.54881|36|701
18:34:34|46|0.45972|27|610
18:59:56|02|0.36363|08|529
18:59:56|02|0.36363|08|529
18:59:56|02|0.36363|08|529
18:59:56|02|0.36363|08|529
19:06:23|67|0.27054|99|438
19:23:43|56|0.18145|80|347
19:32:45|99|0.09236|71|256
19:43:12|13|0.90327|62|165
19:43:12|13|0.90327|62|165
20:04:00|24|0.81418|53|074
20:38:24|54|0.72509|44|983
20:47:46|75|0.63690|35|892
21:04:59|83|0.54781|26|701
...|...|...|...|...  
06:04:23|67|0.52342|26|345
```

И код:

```
import mysql.connector
from itertools import groupby
import pandas as pd
db= mysql.connector.connect(user='Admin', 
password='Admin',host='Admin',database='admin')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Time,X,Y,Z FROM `data`")
a=[]
for c in cursor:
    a.append(c)
x=pd.Series(a)
result =[list(gr) for _,gr in groupby(j,key=lambda s: s.split()[1][:2])]
r=len(result)
p=[]             
for z in range(len(x)-1):
    current_item, next_item = x[z], x[z+1]
    if current_item[0].strftime("%H")<next_item[0].strftime("%H"):
        p.append(current_item[0].strftime("%H"))
for d in range(0,len(p)):
    s.append(d)
arr = [[] for _ in range(len(p))]
for Varr in arr:
    for r in range(len(p)-1):
            Varr=[]
            current_item, next_item = p[r], p[r+1]
            cursor.execute("SELECT Time,X,Y,Z FROM `dataset` WHERE Time BETWEEN 
'2018-09-06 %s:00:00' AND '2018-09-06 %s:00:00'",(int(current_item), 
int(next_item)))
        for w in cursor:
            Varr.append(w)
    arr.append(Varr)
db.close()
print(arr)
```

Я хочу получить двумерный массив данных, чтобы все значения от `19:00:00-19:59:59` были в одном массиве, а `20:00:00-20:59:59` в другом и так далее. Что-то вроде этого:

```
[[[18:04:23,24,0.63790,45,892],
[18:12:27,32,0.54881,36,701],
[18:34:34,46,0.45972,27,610],
[18:59:56,02,0.36363,08,529],
[18:59:56,02,0.36363,08,529],
[18:59:56,02,0.36363,08,529],
[18:59:56,02,0.36363,08,529]],
[[19:06:23,67,0.27054,99,438],
[19:23:43,56,0.18145,80,347],
[19:32:45,99,0.09236,71,256],
[19:43:12,13,0.90327,62,165],
[19:43:12,13,0.90327,62,165]],
[[20:04:00,24,0.81418,53,074],
[20:38:24,54,0.72509,44,983],
[20:47:46,75,0.63690,35,892]],
[[21:04:59,83,0.54781,26,701]],
[[...,...,...,...,...]],     
[[06:04:23,67,0.52342,26,345]]]
```

И чтобы я мог вызывать каждое число в отдельности:

```
print(arr[0][1][2])
0.54881
```

Что не так в моём коде?

PS: Если есть метод лучше, то пожалуйста подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуйтесь преимуществами Pandas:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)

# fetch data from the DB
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT Time,X,Y,Z FROM data", conn)

# grouping
res = [x.values.tolist() for _,x in df.groupby(df['Время'].str.split(':').str[0])]
```

результат:

```
>>> print(res)

[[['18:04:23', 24, 0.6379, 45, 892],
  ['18:12:27', 32, 0.54881, 36, 701],
  ['18:34:34', 46, 0.45971999999999996, 27, 610],
  ['18:59:56', 2, 0.36363, 8, 529],
  ['18:59:56', 2, 0.36363, 8, 529],
  ['18:59:56', 2, 0.36363, 8, 529],
  ['18:59:56', 2, 0.36363, 8, 529]],
 [['19:06:23', 67, 0.27054, 99, 438],
  ['19:23:43', 56, 0.18145, 80, 347],
  ['19:32:45', 99, 0.09236, 71, 256],
  ['19:43:12', 13, 0.90327, 62, 165],
  ['19:43:12', 13, 0.90327, 62, 165]],
 [['20:04:00', 24, 0.81418, 53, 74],
  ['20:38:24', 54, 0.72509, 44, 983],
  ['20:47:46', 75, 0.6369, 35, 892]],
 [['21:04:59', 83, 0.54781, 26, 701]]]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. И все же не понимаю почему мой код с присваиванием к массиву массивов не сработал.